# How can I process each element of \SplitArgument succinctly?

Tags: xparse

I am trying to create some functions that handle conditional probability nicely. So far, I have the following:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \prob { >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}} m } {
    \probc #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand \probc { m m } {
    \ensuremath{\mathbb{P}\!\left(#1\IfValueT{#2}{\;\middle\vert\;#2}\right)}
}
```

This seems to work nicely. Now, I want to write a new function `\problm` which does the same thing as `\prob`, but it wraps each of the (1 or possibly 2) arguments in `\texttt`. (The `lm` in `\problm` indicates language model; when writing probabilities in the context of language models, I want to skip having to write `\texttt` around all the inputs to `\prob`.)

In trying to do this, I tried the following:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \problm { >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}} m } {
    \probc \ProcessList{#1}{\texttt}
}
```

However, this does not work. Why does this fail? And how can I accomplish what I am trying to do in a clean, succinct way? Ideally the solution would only use default or `xparse` commands, though if there is a much simpler solution with an entirely different tool set then that could be useful too!

By the way, I know that I could just write a new function `\problmc` which looks almost like `\probc` but has some `\texttt`s inserted, but I would like to reuse the underlying `probc` function.

Comment: By the way, if something I do in the working code in the question could be improved, please let me know! I am new to `xparse`.

Comment: Doesn't `\NewDocumentCommand \problm { >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}} m } { \problmc #1 }` and `\NewDocumentCommand \problmc { m m } {\probc{\texttt{#1}}{\texttt{#2}}}` solve your issue?

Comment: I guess you're not using the functions in a context where spaces are ignored, so you should improve your code by removing the stray spaces, put a `%` after the `{` to remove the space at the beginning of your definition, and a `%` after the `}` which closes `\ensuremath`.

Comment: Also, `\ensuremath` doesn't really help to make the code clearer, I'd prefer dropping it, even if this requires two more keystrokes in the document.

Comment: @Skillmon I don't think that works since then `-NoValue-` does not work properly. Do you agree?

Comment: @Skillmon What do the extra spaces do here?

Comment: yes, the no-value test wouldn't work that way, which is why I wrote my answer which deals with that.

Comment: The spaces are included in your macro's definition. Now each time you use your macro you're putting a space at the beginning and end of your macro's replacement text. So `A\problm{a|b}` would be the same as `A $\mathbb{P}...$ `, instead of `A$\mathbb{P}...$`, which is what you wanted. And TeX won't ignore consecutive spaces here, so `A \problm{a|b}` will produce two spaces instead of one in your output.

Answer (score 2):

I would define a generic command, to which we can pass the “decoration” for the real arguments we want.

It seems more complicated than you expect, because I really don't like using `\left` and `\right` unconditionally.

You can follow the various cases to see how the size of the parentheses and of the middle delimiter is chosen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\NewDocumentCommand{\genericprob}{m s o >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m }{%
  % #1 = decoration, #2 = * for automatic sizing, #3 = optional size
  % #4 = argument
  \mathbb{P}
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}
    {% automatic sizing
     \!\left(%
     \genericprobaux{#1}{\;\middle|\;}#4%
     \right)%
    }%
    {% no automatic sizing
     \IfNoValueTF{#3}
       {% normal size
        (\genericprobaux{#1}{\mid}#4)%
       }
       {% optional sizing
        \mathopen{#3(}\genericprobaux{#1}{\mathrel{#3|}}#4\mathclose{#3)}%
       }%
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\genericprobaux}{mmmm}{%
  #1{#3}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{#2#1{#4}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\prob}{}{\genericprob{}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\problm}{}{\genericprob{\mathtt}}

\begin{document}

First of all a paragraph to show why it is in general not advisable to
use automatic sizing; here's an example inspired from a picture in Math.SE
taken from a paper typeset with \TeX{} where \verb|\prob*| does
automatic size $\prob*{\bigcup\limits_{g\in B_j}g(R)}$; this uses the
dreaded \verb|\limits|, but even without it the result is not optimal:
compare $\prob*{\bigcup_{g\in B_j}g(R)}$ with $\prob[\big]{\,\bigcup_{g\in B_j}g(R)}$
and judge for yourself.
\begin{gather*}
\prob{x}\ne\prob{x|y}
\\
\prob[\Big]{x}\ne\prob[\bigg]{x|y}
\\
\prob*{\frac{x}{2}}\ne\prob*{\frac{x}{2}|y}
\\
\problm{x}\ne\problm{x|y}
\\
\problm[\Big]{x}\ne\problm[\bigg]{x|y}
\\
\problm*{\frac{x}{2}}\ne\problm*{\frac{x}{2}|y}
\end{gather*}
Inspiring picture at \texttt{https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4038452/62967}

\end{document}
```

Of course, the last line doesn't really make sense, it's just for illustration.

The paragraph before the displayed equations shows why automatic
sizing is not the best. I believe that the example is self-explanatory. In the formula using `\big`, a thin spaces was needed. Typesetting is not simple, but with some experience, these clashes will be seen even before looking at the printout.

What about `\ensuremath`? You just lose semantics in exchange of two keys.

Most important: how does `\prob` not have an argument? Because its definition consists of `\genericprob{}` and the rest of the arguments are grabbed by this more general macro. This avoids code duplication: we can define `\problm` and other commands with different “decorations”.

[image]

Comment: Why are people against automatic sizing? It seems like it is not only convenient but it ensures consistency.

Comment: Also, why no `\ensuremath`? What negative aspects do you have in mind?

Comment: This seems like a really interesting solution. I am confused by what is going on in a few places though. For example, just the line `\NewDocumentCommand{\prob}{}{\genericprob{}}` is confusing to me. How do the arguments get passed to `\genericprob` if `\prob` does not take any arguments?

Comment: @Grayscale see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: @Grayscale Automatic size more often than not choose too big delimiters; just seen an example at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4038452/62967 . About `\ensuremath`, my opinion is that math should always be input as a properly marked math formula and using `\ensuremath` so has more disadvantages than advantages.

Comment: @Grayscale I added a couple of examples to show why automatic sizing is not generally the best and some comments about the definitions.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand most of what is going on. Another thing though: what are the `\mathopen`, `\mathrel`, `\mathclose` doing? Why not have them in the automatic sizing or normal sizing cases? Also, the definitions of `\prob` and `\problm` are still a bit mysterious to me. My intuition is still that the compiler would just not look for any arguments to grab because the functions are declared with no arguments; meanwhile, `\genericprob` is being called with none or one argument, and I don’t understand why this inner function would just “grab” arguments outside of its scope.

Comment: On the latter point, maybe be the issue is that I am trying to think of them as functions (in a C sort of sense), as opposed to macros that just get expanded?

Comment: @Grayscale The TeX language is as far from C as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

Your `\ProcessList` isn't evaluated before `\probc`, so as arguments `\probc` takes `\ProcessList` and `{#1}`, which obviously isn't what you want. Instead, you can introduce another wrapper macro that will put `\texttt` around your input.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[]{amssymb}

\NewDocumentCommand \prob { >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}} m }
  {\probc #1}

\NewDocumentCommand \probc { m m }
  {\mathbb{P}\!\left(#1\IfValueT{#2}{\;\middle\vert\;#2}\right)}

\NewDocumentCommand \problm { >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}} m } 
  {\problmc#1}
% we have to test for a value here as well, otherwise the value test in `\probc` wouldn't work due to the `\texttt`.
\NewDocumentCommand \problmc { m m }
  {\IfValueTF{#2}{\probc{\texttt{#1}}{\texttt{#2}}}{\probc{\texttt{#1}}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
$\problm{language1}$
$\problm{language1|language2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; this is helpful! This seems like a simple solution for this case, though it might be nice to avoid having an extra helper function `\problmc`, and it seems like it would quickly become unwieldy if there were more arguments that `\SplitArgument` is producing.